# Customize CorePlot gridLineStyle

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-plot

In my CorePlot implementation I have a grid line style that looks like this:

[image]

I implement it as simple as that:

```
CPTMutableLineStyle *gridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
gridLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor grayColor];
gridLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.6f;
```

What I'd like to have, though, is the line style that would look like this:

[image]

Any ideas of how do you customize `CPTMutableLineStyle` to make my line be like this? I haven't found anything similar in CorePlotExamples sample project by CorePlot. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Plot supports most of the built-in Core Graphics line drawing properties. The `dashPattern` is the property you need. It supports simple dotted or dashed lines as well as more complex dash patterns.

The "Control Chart" sample in the *Plot Gallery* example app shows several examples.

Comment: Amazing! Saved my life! I did it like this: `CPTMutableLineStyle *gridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    gridLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor grayColor];
    gridLineStyle.dashPattern = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1], [NSNumber numberWithInteger:5], nil];
    gridLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.3f;`